# Clickhouse starts with error: Cannot get pipe capacity

Tags: clickhouse

After installing clickhouse using apt-get, I try to start it

```
sudo -u clickhouse clickhouse-server --config-file=/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml
```

but it doesn't start with an error

```
Application: DB::ErrnoException: Cannot get pipe capacity, errno: 22, strerror: Invalid argument
```

full log:

```
Include not found: clickhouse_remote_servers
Include not found: clickhouse_compression
Logging trace to /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.log
Logging errors to /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log
Logging trace to console
2019.08.28 11:26:50.255115 [ 1 ] {} <Information> : Starting ClickHouse 19.13.3.26 with revision 54425
2019.08.28 11:26:50.255253 [ 1 ] {} <Information> Application: starting up
2019.08.28 11:26:50.260659 [ 1 ] {} <Debug> Application: Set max number of file descriptors to 1048576 (was 1024).
2019.08.28 11:26:50.260715 [ 1 ] {} <Debug> Application: Initializing DateLUT.
2019.08.28 11:26:50.260733 [ 1 ] {} <Trace> Application: Initialized DateLUT with time zone 'America/New_York'.
2019.08.28 11:26:50.261086 [ 1 ] {} <Debug> Application: Configuration parameter 'interserver_http_host' doesn't exist or exists and empty. Will use 'virtual.rysev' as replica host.
2019.08.28 11:26:50.264129 [ 1 ] {} <Debug> ConfigReloader: Loading config '/etc/clickhouse-server/users.xml'
Include not found: networks
2019.08.28 11:26:50.265577 [ 1 ] {} <Information> Application: Uncompressed cache size was lowered to 512.00 MiB because the system has low amount of memory
2019.08.28 11:26:50.265908 [ 1 ] {} <Information> Application: Mark cache size was lowered to 512.00 MiB because the system has low amount of memory
2019.08.28 11:26:50.265955 [ 1 ] {} <Information> Application: Loading metadata from /var/lib/clickhouse/
2019.08.28 11:26:50.267614 [ 1 ] {} <Debug> Application: Loaded metadata.
2019.08.28 11:26:50.267981 [ 1 ] {} <Information> Application: Shutting down storages.
2019.08.28 11:26:50.268287 [ 1 ] {} <Debug> Application: Shutted down storages.
2019.08.28 11:26:50.269839 [ 1 ] {} <Debug> Application: Destroyed global context.
2019.08.28 11:26:50.270149 [ 1 ] {} <Error> Application: DB::ErrnoException: Cannot get pipe capacity, errno: 22, strerror: Invalid argument
2019.08.28 11:26:50.270181 [ 1 ] {} <Information> Application: shutting down
2019.08.28 11:26:50.270194 [ 1 ] {} <Debug> Application: Uninitializing subsystem: Logging Subsystem
2019.08.28 11:26:50.270265 [ 3 ] {} <Information> BaseDaemon: Stop SignalListener thread
```

pls, help

Comment: Could you provide the *config.xml*, cluster topology description?

Comment: What is the platform (OS & version, do you use docker?) ? Do you use a custom build? Where did you download the package? How exactly do you run the ClickHouse?

Answer (score 0):

you could try run following commands:

```
systemctl enable clickhouse-server
systemctl start clickhouse-server
```

also you can try figure out how properly run clickhouse-server

```
less /lib/systemd/system/clickhouse-server.service
```

Comment: tnx, but the problem is still presents

Comment: do you need start clickhouse-server as daemon, or you need just  run clickhouse-server binary manually?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message when installing clickhouse on a CentOS 7 docker image which was started on a CentOS 6 host (kernel-2.6.32).

The issue seems to be related to a change in clickhouse 19.12:

```
TraceCollector.cpp:52
int pipe_size = fcntl(trace_pipe.fds_rw[1], F_GETPIPE_SZ);
```

**F_GETPIPE_SZ** is available in Linux **kernel >=2.6.35**, so this might be the issue.

So you can manually install an older version of clickhouse through the repository or update your kernel.

rpm: https://repo.yandex.ru/clickhouse/rpm/stable/x86_64/

deb: https://repo.yandex.ru/clickhouse/deb/stable/main/

I tried clickhouse version 19.11.8.46-2 and it instantly worked.